# How to convert several MSG-IDs in xml at once?

Tags: conversion, xml

I have a Script which can convert MSG-IDs (MSG-ID placed on our DB) into XML files.

Here an Example for converting one MSID into XML

```
getDXML xxxxxMSGIDxxxxxx > filename.xml
```

now I have more than 40 MSG-IDs and I want to convert them all at once with different names if possible

Here a part of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message schemaLocation="http://postfinance.ch/deva/message BANCS_DEVA_Message.xsd">
    <MessageHeader>
        <MandantID>001001</MandantID>
        <MessageID>**201711221731-A_DEVA_ADHCORDNTF_AA-10500879**</MessageID>
        <Sender>BOMC</Sender>
        <SenderPlattform>T</SenderPlattform>
        <MessageType>00761</MessageType>
        <Receiver>DEVA</Receiver>
        <CommPattern>FF</CommPattern>
        <Prioritaet>normal</Prioritaet>
    </MessageHeader>
    <sendung>
        <ProcessingHeader>
```

Comment: We need to see an example of the file that includes one of these MessageIDs, along with the desired result. Otherwise all we might assume `getDXML` needed to do was to wrap its argument with `<root>` and `</root>`.

Comment: i did adjust my question above

Comment: @ramadnay, also post the desired output

Comment: XSLT is a very nice and unfairly forgotten technology.

Comment: @peterh maybe it's the awful documentation and dearth of examples for common solutions that it is missing. (Also wouldn't help here because we've not been given well-formed XML.)

Answer (score 1):

First create the template

```
cat >template.notxml <<'X'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message schemaLocation="http://postfinance.ch/deva/message BANCS_DEVA_Message.xsd">
    <MessageHeader>
        <MandantID>001001</MandantID>
        <MessageID>#MESSAGEID#</MessageID>
        <Sender>BOMC</Sender>
        <SenderPlattform>T</SenderPlattform>
        <MessageType>00761</MessageType>
        <Receiver>DEVA</Receiver>
        <CommPattern>FF</CommPattern>
        <Prioritaet>normal</Prioritaet>
    </MessageHeader>
    <sendung>
        <ProcessingHeader>
X
```

Now create the files. I assume that you have your set of Message IDs in a list. In the absence of real detail I further assume that your Message IDs contain only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`, `_`). Let's call this list `ids.list`.

```
while IFS= read -r messageid
do
    sed "s/#MESSAGEID#/$messageid/g" template.notxml > "$messageid.notxml"
done < ids.list
```

Comment: i think you missunderstood my Question, or i didnt explain it Good enough. What i Need ist extreme simple, with my script getDXML i can convert just one at the time. i Need a commend so that can happen --> getDxml xxxxxMSGIDxxxxx AND xxxxMSGIDxxxx > filename1.xml; filename2.xml, is that possibale in anyway ??

Comment: @ramadnay if this answer doesn't address the question you had in your mind, please UPDATE YOUR QUESTION to explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve. Examples help tremendously because they reduce the amount of guesswork someone has to do.